# How to set a variable in cmd which is a string from powershell command result?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to store the result of powershell command in cmd variable as String : `powershell -com "(ls | select -Last 1).FullName"`. How to do this?

Comment: Needs clarification, do you want to store the results in a powershell variable or a cmd variable if in powershell then `$VariableName = ls | select -Last 1` in cmd you would use a `for /f` loop to parse tue results in to variables

Comment: i want to store the result in cmd

Comment: ok so this is the answer: `for /f %A in ('powershell -com "(ls | select -Last 1).FullName"') Do @Set "myvariable=%A"`

Comment: It will be multiple results, each line is aseparate string, so you can set the 1st, 9r past 9r put them end to end in a variable with somesort of delimiter or make a wholeset of variables, not sure which 8s your need

Comment: with `powershell -com "(ls | select -Last 1).FullName"` I get only one line result...

Comment: @stakowerflol Sorry I read it and couldn't tell quickly on my phone earlier our're right that it only has one line output.  You could also write it all native CMD for Jenkins.

Answer (score 3):

CMD does not have a straightforward way of assigning command output to a variable. If the command produces just a single line you could use a `for` loop

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('some_command /to /run') do @set "var=%a"
```

However, if the command produces multiple lines that will capture only the last line. A better approach would be redirecting the output of the command to a file and then reading that file into a variable:

```
set "tempfile=C:\temp\out.txt"
>"%tempfile%" some_command /to /run
set /p var=<"%tempfile%"
del /q "%tempfile%"
```

If you literally need only the last file in a directory you don't need to run PowerShell, though. That much CMD can do by itself:

```
for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir /a-d /b') do @set "var=%~ff"
```

Beware that you need to double the `%` characters when running this from a batch file.

Comment: the problem with cmd here is that I want to get the full paths for FOLDERs NOT recursive... this `dir /ad /b` doesn't give full paths and this  `dir /ad /b /s` does it recursively...

Comment: @stakowerflol: `%~ff` takes care of that. See the "modifier" section of `for /?`

Comment: When I run `for /f "delims=" %f in ('dir C:\fodlertosearch /a-d /b') do @set "var=%~ff"` then I get a results for C:\foldertosearch but when I put the code to .bat file and run it then the results are for the directory of a .bat file instead of C:\foldertosearch :O

Comment: @stakowerflol If you want a file from a particular directory: `cd` into that directory before running the loop.

Answer (score 1):

A FOR loop can provide the path to the file. If the default directory sorting order is not the result needed, specify additional command line switches on the `DIR` command.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %F IN ('DIR /B') DO (SET "THE_FILE=%~fF")
ECHO THE_FILE is "%THE_FILE%"
```

In a .bat file script, double the percent characters on FOR loop variables.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('DIR /B') DO (SET "THE_FILE=%%~fF")
ECHO THE_FILE is "%THE_FILE%"
```

The .bat file scripts can also run PowerShell scripts. It is best practice to not use aliases such as `ls` in scripts.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%F IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "(Get-ChildItem -File | Select-Object -Last 1).FullName"') DO (SET "THE_FILE=%%~fF")
ECHO THE_FILE is "%THE_FILE%"
```

Comment: why `%%~fF` instead of `%%~ff`?

Comment: @stakowerflol Because the loop variable is `%F`, not `%f`. Loop variable names are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem with cmd here is that I want to get the full paths for
>   FOLDERs NOT recursive... this dir /ad /b doesn't give full paths and
>   this dir /ad /b /s does it recursively... – stakowerflol 2 hours ago

That's not a problem, you can return the full file path without recursing.

If you are changing directory to the path you need to check then it's stored in `%CD%`

If you need the path to whee the Script itself is it's stored in `%~dp0`

If you want to provide an argument to specify and arbitrary path and get all of the listings it will be that argument term (EG `%~1`)

With all three possible options you can do the same thing:

Either

Prepend the provided variable to the output of the chosen directory enumeration method

OR

Use a For loop to get the file names at that path and show the result with the full path.

IE

### Jenkins_A_Dir.bat

```
@(
  SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_Last="
  ECHO.%~1 | FIND /I ":\" > NUL && (
   SET "_CheckHere=%~1"
  )
  IF NOT DEFINED _CheckHere (
    SET "_CheckHere=C:\Default\Path\When\No Argument\Specified"
  )
)

REM Use a For loop to get everything in one variable

FOR %%A IN (
  "%_CheckHere%\*"
) DO (
  SET "_Last=%%A"
)
ECHO.Found "%_Last%"


REM Use `FOR /F` with DIR, and append the path to Check:

SET "_Last="
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%A IN ('
  DIR /A-D /B "%_CheckHere%\*"
') DO (
  SET "_Last=%_CheckHere%\%%A"
)
ECHO.Found "%_Last%"
```

**Of course you don't NEED to have set a variable such as `_CheckHere`**

Instead, you can just replace all of the instances of `%_CheckHere%` with `%~1 instead, that would work just fine in the above examples too.

**Okay, what if you just wanted to check the location the script was running in.**

Then either change the above to use `SET "_CheckHere=%~dp0"` or Replace `%_CheckHere%` with `%~dp0` throughout.

**Okay but what if you don't want to set a variable you want to it to use the current working directory.**

When then, even easier:

### Jenkins_Current_Dir.bat

```
@(
  SETLOCAL
  ECHO OFF
  SET "_Last="
)

REM Use a For loop to get everything in one variable

FOR %%A IN (
  "*"
) DO (
  SET "_Last=%%~fA"
)
ECHO.Found "%_Last%"


REM Use `FOR /F` with DIR, and let it append the current working directory to the path:

SET "_Last="
FOR /F "Tokens=*" %%A IN ('
  DIR /A-D /B "*"
') DO (
  SET "_Last=%%~fA"
)
ECHO.Found "%_Last%"
```